# Bootstrap 3, how to have some spacing in navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I host my coding and preview here
http://bootply.com/81729

I would like to have some spacing before my home button, please show me how to code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some margin.

```
.navbar-header{
  margin-left:100px;
 }
```

Check this.
[Demo](http://bootply.com/81731)